# Почему в одних случаях надо указывать метод cin.exceptions() для обработки исключений, а в других - нет?

Tags: c++, исключения

Случай, в котором исключение не будет ловиться, если не указать cin.exceptions():
...

```
cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit);
cout << "Вводите резльтаты игры в гольф (введите не число, если хотите закончить):\n";
int num;
bool finish = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << "Введите результат № " << i + 1 << ": ";
    try {
        cin >> num;
    }
    catch (istream::failure e) { //БЕЗ cin.exceptions() НЕ СРАБОТАЕТ
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Ввод прекращен.\n";
        break;
    }
    arr.push_back(num);
}
```

...

Но в другой программе всё сработает и без cin.exceptions():
(ПРИМЕР С САЙТА cplusplus.com: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/?kw=exception ])

```
// exception example
#include <iostream>       // std::cerr
#include <typeinfo>       // operator typeid
#include <exception>      // std::exception

class Polymorphic {virtual void member(){}};

int main () {
  try
  {
    Polymorphic * pb = 0;
    typeid(*pb);  // throws a bad_typeid exception
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "exception caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Почему в одних случаях надо передавать функции cin.exceptions() аргументы, а в других нет? Как понять когда надо, а когда нет?

Comment: Ничего не понял. Во втором примере же `cin` не используется. При чем тут `cin.exceptions()`?

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, то дело в том, что в этих двух примерах Вы пытаетесь ловить разные классы исключений. В первом примере Вы хотите поймать исключения потока, а функция cin.exceptions() позволяет Вам настроить маску исключений, т.е. указать, какие из исключений потока Вы хотите ловить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему в одних случаях надо передавать функции cin.exceptions() аргументы, а в других нет?

А где этот "другой" случай? В втором примере объект `std::cin` вообще не используется.

Что касается первого примера:

```
cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit);
```

Здесь Вы устанавливаете маску исключений для стандартного потока ввода. Если при чтении из потока происходит ошибка, по-умолчанию исклчючение не генерируется. Однако, если маска была установлена (не "пустая", разумеется), исключение будет выброшено.

Answer (score 2):

- В первом случаи функция  генерирует  исключение std::istream::failure (это исключение генерируется только для потоков),
  чтобы на месте обработать исключительную ситуацию, связанную с потоком ввода(если формат ввода не соответствует или поток сломался по какой то причине).
- Во втором,  в самом   `typeid`   может генерироваться исключение bad_typeid, 
  если нет информации о типе, и  обработать это исключение должна уже
  вызывающая функция. И тут поток ввода совершенно не причем.